# jquery UI datepicker format (CF7 Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, datepicker

I'm trying to change the date format in the default datepicker (using the CF7 plugin in Wordpress), which I assume just uses the basic JQ UI datepicker. But I have no idea if I can even apply jquery to it manually? I just need to change the date format to yyyy/mm/dd

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) you can change the dateformat in jQuery UI datepicker like

> **`dateFormat`** 
>   The format for parsed and displayed dates. For a full list of the
>   possible formats see the formatDate function.

Here remember

```
yy - year (four digit)
```

So finally

```
    $("#date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2rGN/)

Comment: I can't just apply this because it's already being executed in the plugin ;/